# Entity Pattern in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Is there a standard entity pattern in the redux framework/library?

I am fairly new to react/redux, and I am building a simple pie chart application where you can add pie slices and change the pie chart name. (I am using the Immutable js library)

In my reducer the code looks really nasty and bulky :

```
switch (action.type) {

  case 'CREATE_SLICE':

    var myList = imState.getIn(['app', 'pie', 'data'])
    myList = myList.toJS();
    myList.push(action.slice);

    var v = Immutable.fromJS(myList)

    imState = imState.setIn(['app', 'pie', 'data'], v)
    break;

  case 'CHANGE_NAME':
    var newName = action.newName;

    imState = imState.setIn(['app', 'pie', 'name'], newName)

    break;
```

So I decided to refactor this into a type of entity class :

```
class PieChart {

  static get path() {
    return ['app', 'pie'];
  }

  static createSlice(imState, action) {

    var myList = imState.getIn([...this.path, 'data'])
    myList = myList.toJS();
    myList.push(action);

    var v = Immutable.fromJS(myList)

    imState = imState.setIn([...this.path, 'data'], v)

    return imState;
  }

  static changeName(imState, newName) {
    imState = imState.setIn([...this.path, 'name'], newName)

    return imState;
  }
}
```

This class contains no state. It only gets the state object passed to it via functions.

A path function contains the path inside the state object to the entity that the class is concerned with.

My question is, is this a common pattern? Is this an appropriate way to encapsulate entity data or functionality?

Comment: How you refactor is completely up to you. As long as each of these methods are pure methods it doesn't matter. I personally see no benefit to creating a class. But creating functions isn't a problem.

Comment: ^I second Callum. If you only have static methods inside your class, why not just export them as stand-alone utility functions? Now moving to your question- Yes it'll be useful to have a small entity library that parses the data. But I don't know any standard library since data from backend will vary greatly.

Answer (score 0):

This would generally be considered an anti-pattern.  Redux encourages use of plain data, and plain functions to manipulate that data.  You don't need to wrap up that data into entity classes just to work with it.